# .apk file build with Rhohub not working on the device

Tags: android, apk, rhomobile

After installing the .apk file in my device ,when i am trying to open it it is saying Unfortunately the application has stopped.
Its working fine on my Rhomobile's Android Rhosimulator,then I cant understand why it is saying so.

Update:
Today I built the .apk file in my local machine which size is 11mb compare to the size of the .apk file which I had built on Rhohub which was 3.5mb,One interesting fact is that the file built on local machine is working but it has created 2 more problems:
1. The .apk file size is too much for a simple application which my fellow developer had built purely on android and java and it was 1 mb.
2. The css file which I has included is working some time when I open the application and some times it doesn't work.

Guys can you help me to reduce the file size I know that being cross platform(Rhomobile) size may be large but 11 times more is too much.

Comment: There are certain differences between Emulator and real device. Please post the Logact output, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @Thommy I dont have a logact output file instead it is Rholog.txt

Comment: With Eclipse or ADB Commandline you can get the logcat directly from the device. See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: But motorolla has already removed the support for using Rhodes from Eclipse.Now with Rhomobile Studio I only get Rholog.txt

Comment: This has nothing to do with Motorola or Exclipse. You just need the Android-SDK from Google. There download the Extras Package and use Command-Line Tool ADB. I'm sorry but this is beginner knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I dont know how it happened, I think because I didn't try to run the application with any other android versions.
So finally my application was created successfully and built with only 2.5mb.

Answer (score 0):

Same is the case with me. I just have Rholog.txt and i have a question, do we need Android SDK on local system configured in Rhostudio to make the app work on actual android device.

For testing i use rhosimulator inside rhostudio.

Comment: Yes for Simulator to work you have to configure the Android SDK and make avd accordingly for the app to work. Rhosimulator is an emulator it is good for testing because it is fast but for making it work on the device you have to configure the SDK according to your requirement.

Comment: What i understood is, to check on android simulator i need SDK, but i dont need it if i want to check directly on device, without rhostudio